# Incrementing and printing variable in the same for loop

Tags: c, scope, printf

I am trying to increment variable x in a for loop and print it on each iteration.

```
include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;

void main()
{    
    int c;
    for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++)

        x++;
        printf("%d", x);

}
```

The output I want is:

```
12345
```

However this code only prints:

```
5
```

When I do not increment x, I am able to print on every iteration:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;

void main()
{    
    int c;
    for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++)

        //x++;
        printf("%d", x);

}
```

Outputs:

```
00000
```

Why does incrementing x in the loop change the behaviour of printf?

Comment: You're missing curly braces around your code block.

Comment: You might be from a Python background. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you are missing a *block scope* here.

The statements

```
for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++)

    x++;
    printf("%d", x);
```

is the same as

```
for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
{
    x++;
}
printf("%d", x);
```

so, your print statement is not part of the loop.

On the other hand, when you comment the `x++;` statement, the `printf()` statement is considered as the body of the loop.

You need to enforce the block using braces, like

```
for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
{
    x++;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The body of your for loop comprises just one command, i.e. `x++;`. Note that the compiler does not care about indentation but just about curly braces.

Write...

```
for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++) {
    x++;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```